# silverlight background colour of a particular row

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have a datagrid which is bound to a list of objects.

Based on the problem domain I know that I will always have 7 rows and 8 columns.

How can I set the background style of a particular row, or a particular column.

I tried writing a style with particular triggers but this doesnt seem valid in silverlight, only wpf

thanks

Comment: Have you tried the `AddingNewItem` or `AutoGeneratingColumn` events? By the way, how did you set your triggers?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
private void dataGrid1_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {

                if (Your condition)
                {
                    e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                }

        }
```